# How do I get my button to move with my .animate width expansion?

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs, one is set to activate an animation on the other. One button div and one content div.

The animation works, but the content covers the button when it plays through.  How do I keep the div (button) spaced the same distance on the right, before and after the animation?  Essentially, moving to the right as its neighbor expands to the right?  I am sure this is a CSS issue, but I am new to this so I am not sure.

JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".about").click(function() {
        $(".aboutContent").animate({ width: "toggle"},"350");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="about"></div>
    <div class="aboutContent"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
    width:940px;
    height:450px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
.about { 
    margin-left:10px;
    width:30px;
    border:dashed 1px #C1C1C1;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:2;
}
.aboutContent  {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:-1px;
    width:900px;
    height:450px;
    display:none;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Well, you do have a fixed width on `#container`. Is there a chance you could create and example here? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I used the `toggle()` function and some specific CSS and animation adjustments to reproduce the affect you want (based on a 300px expansion for the purpose of demo, but you can easily change it to 900px like you require):

```
$(".about").toggle(function() {
    $(".aboutContent").css({
        display: 'block',
        width: '0'
    }).animate({
        display: "block",
        width: 300
    });
    $(".about").animate({
        "margin-left": "+=300"
    });
}, function() {
    $(".aboutContent").animate({
        width: 0
    }, function() {
        $(this).hide()
    });
    $(".about").animate({
        "margin-left": "-=300"
    });
});
```

[**See demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGT5u/)

Comment: jQuery allows these in order to take whatever the value of the specified CSS property is and add or subtract the given value to it.  So if `margin-left` was 150px, after `+=300` it will animate to 450px.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML and CSS to the following. No need to change your jQuery.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NWZKN/

```
<div class="container">    
    <span class="about">about</span>
    <span class="aboutContent">content</span>
</div>
```

```
.about {
    border:dashed 1px #C1C1C1;
    cursor:pointer;   
}
.aboutContent  {
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
```